# In akka, How do you create a sibling actor from with in an actor

Tags: akka

The end goal is to clone or copy an actor. This copy would have the same parent.

From within an actor one can create a child actor with context.actorOf(). I don't want this new actor to be the manager of the new actor. I want the parent of the actor to be the manager.

Answer (score 2):

First off, `context.system.actorOf` does ***not*** create a child actor, that creates a top-level actor.

If you want to create a sibling actor, send a message to the parent `context.parent` and send it a message requesting a new actor.  Actors can only create child actors (or top-level actors as above).

Comment: Yeah, I thought of doing that, but I was hoping for an easy way to get the parents context.

Comment: A specific `ActorContext` isn't safe to share outside of that actor.